# How do I create a Secure submit form in Spring 3.0.3?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring (formerly a Struts guru) and I've decide to change all my code to Spring for the reason being that Spring is more Service-Oriented (and the possibility that I might also include a RESTful application form the same project is a possible option).

As for now, in Struts, there was an SSL plugin to create a secure HTTPS form. How do I do that in Spring? I've read Spring Security but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the SpringSecurity reference - [Section 2.3.2. Adding HTTP/HTTPS Channel Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-requires-channel).  This gives you a simple way to declare that a URL or set of URLs must be accessed via HTTPS.  (IIRC, this works by configuring a ChannelProcessingFilter which will automatically redirect requests to the appropriate protocol if necessary.)

Comment: It's a start, I'll try and see how to do this for secure online transaction such as credit card purchasing.